# Reconnecting Spring application to Kafka Brokers to produce messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following singleton bean as a Producer.

```
@Bean
public KafkaProducer<String, String> buildProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapServerUrl);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class.getName());
    
    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);

}
```

and then

```
@Autowired
private KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer;
```

and I use kafkaProducer.send() method to produce the message. However, one of the brokers went down and the application did not re-establish the connectivity. I thought, Kafka Producer will reestablish the connection after 5 mins. However, it didn't establish the connection. Can you please let us know how can we make the application to reconnect to Kafka?

Comment: How many URLs did you provide to the property value?

Comment: What is the value if 'bootstrapServerUrl' ?

Comment: Only one. There is a load balancer in front of the brokers.